# How do I use canned comments?

Tags: support, review-queues, comments

I want to help review questions but I can't seem to figure out how all you folks comment with those oh-so-appropriate comments that link to how to ask a question or how to provide a minimally reproducible example of the problem.  I tried adding things like [ask] to my comments but I don't think it works the way I think it does.

Comment: i use book marks, and a clipboard manger myself.

Comment: In addition to the magic comments discussed in Josh's answer, you might also find it handy to use a snippet-expansion tool. For example, on Windows, I use AutoHotKey (free), and on my Mac, I use TextExpander (alas, not free).

Comment: [meta] [so] [help]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The magic comment links like `[ask]` are listed on Meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/159251, but it sounds like you may be thinking of the comments that result from the [Low-quality review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/), which you don't have access to yet. You need 2000 rep -- the ability to edit posts -- in order to interact there. ([What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work))

There's also the [Pro-forma comments repository](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments) and associated userscript, which you might find useful.